# Why does `.rename(columns={'b': 'b'}, copy=False)` followed by inplace method not update the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my example:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})

In [3]: df1 = df.rename(columns={'b': 'b'}, copy=False)

In [4]: df1.isetitem(1, [7,8,9])

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [6]: df1
Out[6]:
   a  b
0  1  7
1  2  8
2  3  9
```

If `df1` was derived from `df` with `copy=False`, then I'd have expected an in-place modification of `df1` to also affect `df`. But it doesn't. Why?

I'm using pandas version 2.2.1, with no options (e.g. copy-on-write) enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy=False` means that the underlying data (numpy) is shared.

If we modify one item of the underlying numpy array, it is reflected since the data is shared:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
df1 = df.rename(columns={'b': 'c'}, copy=False)
df1.values[0, 1] = 999

print(df)
   a    b
0  1  999
1  2    5
2  3    6

print(df1)
   a    c
0  1  999
1  2    5
2  3    6

print(id(df.values), id(df1.values))
# 140335530654768 140335530654768
```

The DataFrame objects (containers, indices, column names…) are however not identical.

```
print(id(df), id(df1))
# 140335696175520 140335696171536
```

By setting a new column with `df1.isetitem(1, [7,8,9])` you just add a new Series and force a copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how python handles immutable and mutable objects.

The option `copy=False` only controls whether the data within the dataframe object is to be copied, not the dataframe itself.

Thus, the `rename` functions creates a second `pd.DataFrame` object `df1`, that may share the data with `df`, since `copy=False`. It is, however, still a different dataframe object.

If you want to change both dataframes, you could do the following instead:

```
df.iloc[1] = [7, 8, 9]
```

This modifies both `df` and `df1`.